# issue querying description column in php sql

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-highlighting

UPDATE
Surrounding the conflicting keyword `description` with backticks, not quotations, worked with both the syntax-highlighting issue in VSCode and the results pulled from the table. TIL... So doing it that way from now on.

```
$search = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `film` WHERE `title` LIKE ? OR `description` LIKE ?');
$search->execute([$_POST["search"]."___%", "%". $_POST["search"]."___%"]);
$results = $search->fetchAll();
```

---

First question here. I am building up a practice project using the Sakila database with MySQL (whichever version comes packaged with the free MAMP 5) and PHP 8. I'm using VSCode for my editor. I'd prefer to keep working with the PHP PDO class. I've built a search form to query the film table and it is not getting results from the column labeled `description`. In VSCode the word description appears blue like the keywords. I went and changed the column label to `summary` and my code does just what I want it to and appears in the same color orange as `film` and `title`. I cant find any sources saying that it is a keyword or reserved word. I played around a little with the category table for the futz of it and it appears I will have the same issue with the `name` column in that table. Can anybody tell me why this is? I seem get syntax errors whenever I try "" or '' quotes around them. The syntax errors seem to point to a MySQL version rather than the PHP version. I've found a work around for now but I'd like to avoid such things as my project gets bigger.

```
$film = $sakila_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM film WHERE title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?');
$film->execute([$_POST["search"]."%", "%". $_POST["search"]."%"]);
$results = $film->fetchAll();
```

This did work. and there are a lot of films about a moose.

```
$film = $sakila_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM film WHERE title LIKE ? OR summary LIKE ?');
$film->execute([$_POST["search"]."%", "%". $_POST["search"]."%"]);
$results = $film->fetchAll();
```

Comment: "DESCRIPTION; added in 8.0.4 (nonreserved)" [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Language Structure  /  Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-N)

Comment: Both `DESCRIPTION` and `NAME` are keywords but not reserved. So it actually should work im MySQL. And I can't reproduce the problen in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/kfA2dS-z